# I have a problemusing badget in navigation bar kotlin

Tags: kotlin, badge, materials

I'm tyring to use a badget with Materials but I have several custom styles and when I use it, my custom button's style dissapear

I know that it works If I replace in my manifest

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

with

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

Here is my full manifest

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        tools:targetApi="31">
```

But I have a custom xml to modify my buttons which I attach using the backgroudn property of buttons and when I change the manifest I lose my effects

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:centerX="50%"
        android:centerY="50%"
        android:startColor="#6859C1"
        android:endColor="#34278C"
        android:gradientRadius="100%"
        />

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="30px"/>
</shape>
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the error, you can also use `BadgeDrawable`  [check this one](https://medium.com/@jeremiahpolo/implementing-badge-in-android-95cb17bc70b7)

Comment: I've checked that article sorry I've edited the title there is no crash. The badget works but my buttom style It's not apply